# I can turn on minor modes like electric pair modes in my init, but they’re not having effect unless manually reactivated

Tags: customize, minor-mode, linum-mode, electric-pair-mode

So I can put a line like,
`(setq-default global-linum-mode t)`
or
`(setq-default electric-par-mode t)`
in my init file, and I can check with C-h v that the variables are in fact set to t (they are), but unless I actually M-x them on inside a file, they’re not having any effect. What might be going on?

I’m on an ssh terminal to a Debian Raspberry Pi, if relevant.

Comment: Another near duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17031/105.

Comment: What do you mean M-x them? M-x set-variable?

Comment: @JeanPierre I meant doing this twice: `m-x <mode> RET`, which appears to toggle the variable. The first toggle turns it off (though it never worked as if it was on, the variable claimed to be on, or t, rather), the second turns it on

Comment: @drew Yeah, that solved my problem, thanks. I’m now curious what the difference between customize-set-variable and setq is however, and the post only says that they are different, not what the difference is.

Comment: I think the answer to that other question answers what you're asking: `customize-set-variable' uses the `:set` property for the variable (option), and `setq` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get help for a particular variable via `C-h v global-linum-mode`. This will show you:

> global-linum-mode is a variable defined in ‘linum.el’.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil if Global Linum mode is enabled.
>   See the ‘global-linum-mode’ command
>   for a description of this minor mode.
>   **Setting this variable directly does not take effect;**
>   either customize it (see the info node ‘Easy Customization’)
>   or call the function ‘global-linum-mode’.

So you can either set the value via the customization menu, or call the function `(global-linum-mode)` in your init, instead of using `(setq-default global-linum-mode t)`.

There is a similar message waiting for you behind `C-h v electric-pair-mode`.

Comment: Yep. I’ve taken a look at these. They’re both set to “t”. But my editor doesn’t act like it.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by the customization menu.

Comment: Doing this fixes one problem (the mode turns on and has effect), but causes others: slow startup and an error message about the mode: (`use-package <mode> :ensure t :init (<mode>))

Comment: 1. Setting the variables to `t` doesn't do anything, as the help message states (I put that part in **bold**) 2. Just putting the single line `(global-linum-mode)` in your init shouldn't cause an error related to use-package. I don't think we have all the information we need to fix this.

Comment: Sorry. You did, and I didn’t realize what was meant. I hadn’t considered just putting `(global-linum-mode)` in my init, that actually worked, in addition to `use-package`, and `customize-set-variable`. So now I’m curious why one would ever use `setq`.